# Get iPhone's contacts list in Objective-C

Tags: contacts

I'd like to get my iPhone's contacts list without using the `iOS Navigation Picker`.
Here's the code I wrote...but it's not working, do you know why?

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
CFArrayRef allPeopleRef = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, nil, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

for(int i=0; i<nPeople; i++){
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeopleRef, i );
    CFStringRef tmpStringRef = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSLog(@"FirstName: %@", (__bridge NSString *)tmpStringRef);
    CFRelease(tmpStringRef);
}

CFRelease(allPeopleRef);
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Comment: @gnasher729 Basically I don't get any of my contacts in the output and while running the nPeople value is always equal to "-1"